# Does SignalR api support facebook chat

Tags: c#, facebook, signalr

I've recently integrated the facebook chat in my web application using `strophe` library with `nodeBOSH` and `heroku` as Service . but for me SignalR is more easy to use and understand. I've searched the web to see if i can use it to make a facebook chat but i couldn't find anything so i am asking this question here to see if some of you have an answer for this .Thank you

Comment: Is SignalR an XMPP client library? If not, no

Comment: No SignalR is not an XMPP client library

Comment: Then no, you won't be able to use it to connect to Facebook's Chat API, which is an XMPP server